# checkmarx permission is marked as medium risk

Tags: android

I have the following code in a AndridManifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Checkmarx has identified this statement as "Failure To Implement Least Privilege",I want to solve this problem。

Checkmarx has identified this statement as "Failure To Implement Least Privilege",I want to solve this problem。

Here is my code:
void onGPSClick() {
        final Context context = this;

```
    //Here, thisActivity is the current activity
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ReportGovernmentActivity.this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(ReportGovernmentActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ReportGovernmentActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

            /*
            new AlertDialog.Builder(ReportGovernmentActivity.this)
                    .setMessage("Turn on location permissions to get relevant information!")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ReportGovernmentActivity.this,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
            */
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ReportGovernmentActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
        }
    }else {
        providerLocation();
    }
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS: {

            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                providerLocation();

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.
            } else {
                finish();
                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}

public void providerLocation() {
    if (isLocationEnabled(this)) {
        final RxPermissions rxPermissions = new RxPermissions(this);
        final ReactiveLocationProvider locationProvider = new ReactiveLocationProvider(this);
        rxPermissions.request(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                .flatMap(new Func1<Boolean, Observable<Location>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<Location> call(Boolean aBoolean) {
                        try {
                            return locationProvider.getUpdatedLocation(LocationRequest.create())
                                    .take(1);
                        } catch (SecurityException e) {
                            throw e;
                        }
                    }
                })
                .flatMap(new Func1<Location, Observable<List<Address>>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<List<Address>> call(Location location) {
                        return locationProvider
                                .getReverseGeocodeObservable(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
                    }
                })
                .map(new Func1<List<Address>, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String call(List<Address> addresses) {
                        return addresses.size() > 0 ? addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0) : "";
                    }
                })
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Action1<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(String addresses) {
                        locationView.setText(addresses);
                    }
                }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Throwable e) {
                        Toast.makeText(ReportGovernmentActivity.this, "Positioning failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please turn on location services!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        final Intent intent = new Intent( Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ignore this alert! nothing is wrong with the way you re using permissions! The alert is a false positive. 
I found Checkmarx to be a terrible security tool that produces mostly false positives. they just need to show something in their security scan report to justify their license cost...

Answer (score 0):

more than said if is a good or a bad tool I like to explain why you are getting this result.

When you scan an Android app, the major part of SAST tools report all the permissions. This is based on the minimum usage policy. The tool report all the perms, but in each particular case is the security team the responsible to review if the reported one is really necessary or not.